# how to create array of value from JSON array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Please find my json array, I want to form array of data in below format:

***[Sunday.a_count.value, Monday.a_count.value, Tuesday.a_count.value, Wednesday.a_count.value]*** - This format output will be  **[0, 2, 2, 3]** -

Eventually, these values come from Sunday a_count, Monday a_count, Tuesday a_count and Wednesday a_count.

I'm not able to form the data in above format using below json in javascript, if someone can help to achieve this it will be really helpful.

Thanks!

```
[ {
  "day" : "Sunday",
  "a_count" : 0,
  "b_count" : 2,
  "c_count" : 0,
  "d_count" : 0
}, {
  "day" : "Monday",
  "a_count" : 2,
  "b_count" : 0,
  "c_count" : 0,
  "d_count" : 0
}, {
  "day" : "Tuesday",
  "a_count" : 2,
  "b_count" : 0,
  "c_count" : 0,
  "d_count" : 0
}, {
  "day" : "Wednesday",
  "a_count" : 3,
  "b_count" : 0,
  "c_count" : 0,
  "d_count" : 0
} ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood, you want to get value from `a_count`, you can do it with [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like so

```js
var data = [ {
  "day" : "Sunday",
  "a_count" : 0,
  "b_count" : 2,
  "c_count" : 0,
  "d_count" : 0
}, {
  "day" : "Monday",
  "a_count" : 2,
  "b_count" : 0,
  "c_count" : 0,
  "d_count" : 0
}, {
  "day" : "Tuesday",
  "a_count" : 2,
  "b_count" : 0,
  "c_count" : 0,
  "d_count" : 0
}, {
  "day" : "Wednesday",
  "a_count" : 3,
  "b_count" : 0,
  "c_count" : 0,
  "d_count" : 0
} ];

var res = data.map(function (el) {
  return el.a_count;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I got it.  Thanks for the answer! Appreciate your help